# Entity Framework 4.1 Creating Duplicate Lookup Entries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.1 code first.  I have two classes:

```
 public class Product {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
      public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
 }

 public class ProductType {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

If I have some existing ProductTypes that I have already created (IDs 2,3,4 for example), and I try to assign on one of those ProductTypes to a new product, it will create a duplicate of the Product type.

For example, if my greatest ProductTypeID is 4, and I run the following code, it will produce a duplicate:

```
 Expression<Func<ProductType, bool>> expr = s => s.ID == 2;
 ProductType t = DBContext.Set<ProductType>().Where(expr).First();
 Product p = new Product();
 p.ProductType = t;
 DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will actually create a new row in the "ProductType" table.  The new ProductType will be identical to the one with ID 2, but it will have the new ID 5.  All I am trying to do is associate the type with ID=2 to my new Product.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem -- It works correctly for me.  Even though I don't see you adding any objects to the contexts, see Adi's answer below to start with.  If that answer is not correct, please post more code.

Comment: You're right.  I actually tried to simplify it, and neglected to post the actual problem.  I was trying to implement a repository pattern and ended up creating two distinct DBContext objects (one for the product and one for the type).  After I fixed that, it worked!

Comment: Could you perhaps share some research on this topic as I am struggling with the same issue at the moment and would like to understand what it is that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common mistake using EF.

You need to add the new product to DBContext:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.ProductType = t;
DBContext.AddObject(p); //here
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't actually see a DBContext.AddObject(object) method.  I wonder if it was removed for 4.1?

Comment: There's no AddObject method on DbContext

Answer (score 0):

Why do you load `ProdutType` from database? You have foreign key exposed on your entity so this is what you need:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.ProductTypeId = 2;
DBContext.Products.Add(p);
DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I guess I don't have to load it, but shouldn't it work both ways?